# Search for pattern across multiple files and replace a sub-part in all occurences

Tags: bash, terminal, sed, regular-expression, replace

I am helping a friend with her thesis written in LaTeX and I need a quick solution for a "search and replace". Using a terminal in Linux, how can I find the following pattern:

```
\caption{*\cite{*}}
```

and replace `\cite` with `\protect\cite`

I was using Kate. Using its search feature I initially found more than 2000 hits and by refining my search I narrowed it down to some 300 hits. However I need to narrow it down further because I do not want to replace all `\cite`. I only want to replace `\cite` if it occurs within `\caption{}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the caption and citation text do not contain special characters (in particular, the first `*` in your example should not contain `\` and the second `*` should not contain `}`) then a GNU sed regex

```
s:(\\caption\{[^\]+)(\\cite\{[^}]+\}\}):\1\\protect\2:g
```

should work, I think. If there may be *empty* caption and/or citation strings you may want to change the `+` modifiers to `*`. You can test it without modifying the file(s) using

```
sed -nr 's:(\\caption\{[^\]+)(\\cite\{[^}]+\}\}):\1\\protect\2:gp' files
```

If that seems to find and modify the right instances, then you can make it modify the files in-place using the `-i` option - if you are not already working on separate copies you can make backups automatically

```
sed -i.bak -r 's:(\\caption\{[^\]+)(\\cite\{[^}]+\}\}):\1\\protect\2:g' files
```

Similar expressions are possible in perl if sed doesn't work for you. Other versions of sed should work but may need different escaping of the special characters.